# Alternative to using the sort function when adding to a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to insert a word alphabetically into a list. Originally I would append the word I'm adding to the end of the list and then sort the list, but I am not allowed to use the `sort()` function.

Is there a way to do this through a function?

Comment: Find the place where the word belongs in the list, then use `insert()`

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
array = ["asdf", "bsdf", "kkkk", "zssdd"]
insertion_string = "zzat"
i = 0
for element in array:
  if insertion_string < element:
    array.insert(i, insertion_string)
    break
  i += 1
# if it is last one
if not insertion_string in array:
  array.append(insertion_string)
print (array )
```

Repl.it = https://repl.it/repls/VitalAvariciousCodec

Comment: Instead of checking if the string is in the array, use the `else:` clause of `for`. It will execute if you reach the end of the loop without breaking.

Comment: @Sheshank S. Thanks for this really helped out. I have another question, is using the < operator sufficient for comparing which of two words goes first?  

For example, if I have 'Amy' and 'Alice', I get this: 'Alice' < 'Amy' = True. If Alice is less than Amy, does that mean it comes before or after Amy in a list? Im confused with how python orders strings alphabetically. Thanks!

Comment: @ReneYeri Yes, Python orders string alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

Based of of @SheshankS.'s answer. A function to do this for you:

```
def insert(item, _list):
    for index, element in enumerate(_list):
        if item < element: # in python, this automatically compares alphabetical precedence.
            _list.insert(index, item)
            return # exit out of the function since we already inserted
    # if the item was not inserted, it must have the lowest precedence, so just append it
    _list.append(item)
```

Note that since lists are mutable, this will actually mutate the given instance.

So, this:

```
someList = ["a", "b", "d"]
insert("c", someList)
```

Will actually change `someList` instead of just returning the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say if you are allowed to use third-party modules, and you did not say if speed is a factor. If you want to add a new item to your sorted list quickly and you are allowed to use a module, use the `SortedList` class from [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/). This is a module included in many distributions of Python, such as [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_win-64).

This will be simple and fast, even for large lists.

```
someList = SortedList(["a", "b", "d"])
someList.add("c")
print(someList)
```

The printout from that is

```
SortedList(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import bisect
>>> someList = ["a", "b", "d"]
>>> bisect.insort(someList,'c')
>>> someList
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If standard lib is allowed you can use `bisect`:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> lst = list('abcefg')
>>> for x in 'Adh':
...     lst.insert(bisect.bisect(lst, x), x)
...     print(lst)
... 
['A', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
['A', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']                                                                            
['A', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```